# Why does List<T> implement so many interfaces?

Tags: c#, derived-class

`List<T>` derives from the following interfaces:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

I just wonder, why it needs all these interfaces (**in the class declaration**)?

`IList` itself already derives from `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` und `IEnumerable`.

So why is the following not enough?

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList
```

I hope you can solve my confusion.

Comment: Where do you see that it derives from all of these interfaces? It may just be the tool you are using that is expanding the IList<T> implementors/derivables/any better descriptor.

Comment: I like @AntP explanation; go and look at the definitions of all those interfaces which explains why it needs to implement all of them

Comment: Because of the interface segregation principle? Just good design.

Comment: The only thing `List<T>` **derives** from is `System.Object`, it does however **implement** a lot of interfaces.

Comment: The "Because it implements lots of functionality" argument completely misses the point of the question.

Comment: @Ant P - OP is asking why, if the interface IList already implements these other interfaces, that the class definition also lists all of these interfaces in the declaration.

Comment: I don't like this close votes. I don't think OP asking anyone opinion about that. I think he is asking _why_ is implemented like that.

Comment: How is that opionion based? OP clearly asks why there's a (seemingful) redundancy.

Comment: Because each of these interfaces gives you some functionality: for example, Ienumerable gives you possibility to use keyword foreach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed `List<T>` would have just implemented like this

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList
```

It is the reflector or such decompiler shows you all the interfaces in inheritance.

Try this

```
public class List2<T> : IList<T>
```

I just compiled this and viewed in reflector, which shows like this

```
public class List2<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Comment: I used the type definitions of Visual Studio 2012 and the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @Andy I guess that the MSDN docs flatten the hierarchy so you don't have to look up all the inherited interfaces.

Comment: Its probably just displayed for your reference and completeness. You are not required to list all of these.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a peek into actual .NET source code you'll see that it does not redundantly mention all the interfaces:

```
// Implements a variable-size List that uses an array of objects to store the
// elements. A List has a capacity, which is the allocated length 
// of the internal array. As elements are added to a List, the capacity
// of the List is automatically increased as required by reallocating the
// internal array.
// 
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<>))]
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")] 
[Serializable] 
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
```

The reflector just lists all the interfaces.

You can get the source code of .NET [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), or do a quick search [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/1305376/List@cs) (seems to stuck at .NET4).

Comment: The second link you posted has done something really nasty to the code. Search the doc for `<T>` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @spender Aye, I saw that too - it's definitely the source code for `List<T>` but the HTML formatting has stripped all the `<>`. Also, if you go to its home page (http://www.dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx) and search for `List<T>` it *really* freaks out. :)

Comment: @spender: Well, what can I say... Works on my machine™

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is impossible to deduce how the actual implementation of `List<T>` was actually written. It might have been:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, 
                       ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, 
                       IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
                       IEnumerable
```

or it might have been a simplified version... although I think your example misses out the ReadOnly interfaces, I still understand the point.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList
```

However, in terms of easy comprehension for any future developer (who might not be inclined to scan all the way up the inheritance chain), I think the first form probably has its benefits.